# Do High-Caliber Rounds break sprinting?

Tags: destiny-2

Earlier today, I was playing some Crucible and managed to snag the power ammo for my sword. As I was sprinting around looking for players to swing my sword at, I stumbled upon a small cluster of enemies just out of range.

As I began sprinting toward their group, ready to lay waste, one of them turned and began firing their MIDA Multi-Tool at me. As I hit the crouch key to slide into sword-range in style, I was surprised to find that I didn't slide at all. Instead, I crouched in place, making an easy kill of myself, and my hard fought power ammo.

Does the High-Caliber Rounds perk have a hidden ability to negate a target's sprinting? I'm completely at a loss for what could have happened to my beloved sprint speed.

Comment: They don't negate sprinting, they just cause flinching. It can mess up slides in my experience. But I've also experienced slides just being weird and you not really traveling anywhere. (I think that has to do with whether you are actually running)

Comment: You need some St0mp-EE5!

Answer (score 2):

High caliber rounds effect only aim punch. They do not slow you down; in fact, the only slow effects that can be applied via weapons are the debuffs you find on some grenade launchers (ex. Orwing's Maul) that have flash/concussion grenades. Other than these weapons, slow effects are only found in abilities such as tether.

What happened to you was most likely you fell down a unit or two on some broken terrain- this can be fairly common. If you play hunter, you may occasionally notice that sometimes the game counts one of your 2nd jumps as you jump off the ground, negating one of your in air jumps. This is because your playermodel fell down a very small amount on uneven terrain, so the game thinks you are falling when you jump.

This bug is fairly rare. While annoying, there's nothing you can do to fix it. The only way to minimize the issue is to make sure that you do not have high packet loss, which can cause mesh issues on some maps.